# Compare two files and print matching lines with some lines after match

Tags: awk

I have two files file1.txt and file2.txt.

file1.txt

```
DS496218    40654   42783   
DS496218    40654   42783
DS496218    40654   42783
```

file2.txt

```
###
DS496108    ena gene    99942   102567  .   -       
DS496128    ena mRNA    99942   102567  .   -       
DS496118    ena three_prime_UTR 99942   100571  
###
DS496218    ena gene    40654   42783   .   -       
DS496108    ena mRNA    99942   102567  .   -       
DS496108    ena three_prime_UTR 99942   100571      
###
DS496128    ena gene    99942   102567  .   -       
DS496133    ena mRNA    99942   102567  .   -       
DS496139    ena three_prime_UTR 99942   100571  
###
```

I want to match column 1,2 and 3 of file1.txt with column 1,4 and 5 of file2.txt. If it matches print the matching line with the following lines till `###` but don't print `###`. I tried it with 'awk' command in

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2$3]++;next};c[$1$4$5] > 0' file1.txt file2.txt > out.txt.
```

Comment: Try using the 'in' option. ie:  $1$4$5 in c {do stuff here}

Comment: try with `awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2$3]++; next} $1$4$5 in c' file1.txt RS="###" file2.txt`

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input. @JoseRicardoBustosM. no, never concatenate fields to create a key string unless you have a very specific goal in mind as that produces false matches - consider `a bc` -> `abc` and `ab c` -> `abc`. Also setting RS to multiple chars would make the script unnecessarily gawk-specific and would print the lines before the match as well as after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your expected output it's a guess but it sounds like this is what you want:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { a[$1,$2,$3]; next }
($1,$4,$5) in a { found=1 }
/^###/ { found=0 }
found
' file1 file2
```